# Solr Numeric Overflow

Tags: java, oracle, solr, dataimporthandler

I am having problems with SOLR using DataImportHandler, I am making a connection with oracle 10g database and I need import 160 millions records, but when solr reaches around 60 Millions, he throws a exception and breaks the import:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Overflow Numérico
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4381)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getBigDecimal(NumberCommonAccessor.java:2509)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getObject(NumberCommonAccessor.java:3247)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CNumberAccessor.getObject(T4CNumberAccessor.java:313)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getObject(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1108)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getObject(OracleResultSet.java:462)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.getARow(JdbcDataSource.java:320)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.access$700(JdbcDataSource.java:258)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.next(JdbcDataSource.java:298)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.next(JdbcDataSource.java:290)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase.getNext(EntityProcessorBase.java:133)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:75)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:476)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
```

The configuration is like the follow:

data-config.xml

```xml
<dataConfig>
<dataSource 
    name="DataSourceProduction"
    type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    user="xxxxx"
    password="xxxxx"
    batchSize="100"
/>

<document>

    <entity
        dataSource="DataSourceProduction"
        name="maestroObjectValue"
        pk="id"

        query="SELECT VAL.ID, VAL.OBJECT_VARIANT_ID, VAL.CHARACTERISTIC_ID, VAL.CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID, VAL.VALUE_STRING, VAL.VALUE_NUMBER, VAL.TYPE, VAL.CD_ITEM_EEM, VAL.SEQUENCE, VAL.VALUE_FORMATTED FROM OBJECT_VALUE VAL"

    ><!-- END -->

        <field column="ID" name="ID" /> 
        <field column="OBJECT_VARIANT_ID" name="OBJECT_VARIANT_ID" />
        <field column="CHARACTERISTIC_ID" name="CHARACTERISTIC_ID" />
        <field column="CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID" name="CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID" />
        <field column="VALUE_STRING" name="VALUE_STRING" />
        <field column="VALUE_NUMBER" name="VALUE_NUMBER" />
        <field column="TYPE" name="TYPE" />
        <field column="CD_ITEM_EEM" name="CD_ITEM_EEM" />
        <field column="SEQUENCE" name="SEQUENCE" />
        <field column="VALUE_FORMATTED" name="VALUE_FORMATTED" />

        <entity 
            dataSource="DataSourceProduction"
            name="maestroObjectVariant"
            pk="id"

            query="SELECT OV.OBJECT_HEADER_ID, OV.OBJECT_TYPE_ID FROM OBJECT_VARIANT OV WHERE OV.ID = '${maestroObjectValue.OBJECT_VARIANT_ID}'"
        ><!-- END -->
            <field column="OBJECT_HEADER_ID" name="OBJECT_HEADER_ID" />
            <field column="OBJECT_TYPE_ID" name="OBJECT_TYPE_ID" />             
        </entity>


    </entity>

</document>
```

schema.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><schema name="objectValue" version="1.5">


<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="ID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 

<!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
    via copyField further on in this schema  -->
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>


<field name="OBJECT_VARIANT_ID"         type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="CHARACTERISTIC_ID"         type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE_ID"   type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="VALUE_STRING"              type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="VALUE_NUMBER"              type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="TYPE"                      type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="CD_ITEM_EEM"               type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="SEQUENCE"                  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="VALUE_FORMATTED"           type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="OBJECT_HEADER_ID"          type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="OBJECT_TYPE_ID"            type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>


<uniqueKey>ID</uniqueKey>


<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" />
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" />
<fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" />
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" />
```

Comment: That exception is thrown from your Oracle DB. Those tables are views, right? Are you casting data-types at some point or are you fetching from a sequence? Could you post the queries of your views?

Comment: I verified that, I noticed that in the middle of 160 million record was a tuple with the Infinity value, throwing the exception. Thanks =S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `onError="skip"` to your entity tag.

SOLR DIH docs: [Schema for the data config](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Schema_for_the_data_config)

> onError : (abort|skip|continue) . The default value is 'abort' .
>   'skip' skips the current document. 'continue' continues as if the
>   error did not happen.