# sqoop import fails with numeric overflow

Tags: sqoop

sqoop import job failed caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
 I have to load Oracle table, it has column type NUMBER in Oracle,without scale,  and it's converted to DOUBLE in hive. This is the biggest possible size for both, Oracle and Hive numeric values. The question is how to overcome this error?

Comment: _"NUMBER without scale"_ >> meaning without neither *precision* nor scale i.e. `NUMBER` i.e. `NUMBER(38,*)`?

Comment: Yes, just NUMBER. It would be nice to solve this on hadoop side without talking to Oracle people to fix the value. I can't find anything. Sqoop doesn't allow to change data type during ingestion.

Comment: _"Sqoop doesn't allow to change data type"_ -- really? Can you point to a source that contradicts the official documentation at https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_type_mapping?

Comment: I tried free sql to select this column with to_char(mycolumn) and got an error : caused by : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid nuber

Comment: I tried free sql to select this column with to_char(mycolumn) and got an error : caused by : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number. According to Oracle: "ORA-01722 invalid number
 
    Cause: The attempted conversion of a character string to a number failed because the character string was not a valid numeric literal. Only numeric fields or character fields containing numeric data may be used in arithmetic functions or expressions...."  It failed on all mappers, not just on one mapper with bad value. So I concluded...

Comment: That Oracle error message can be produced by TO_NUMBER, not by TO_CHAR. I strongly suspect that you are querying a **view** containing a **formula** _(which would be consistent with the generic NUMBER type)_ and not an actual table. Can you check the status of the object via `ALL_TABLES` vs. `ALL_VIEWS`? Can you run a direct SQL query such as `SELECT MAX(z) FROM wtf`? If the SQL query fails, then contact your DBAs and yell at them until they debug their crappy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my first answer assumed that your Oracle data was good, and your Sqoop job needed specific configuration to cope with *NUMBER* values.

But now I suspect that **your Oracle data contains shit**, and specifically **`NaN` values, as a result of calculation errors**.
See that post for example: [When/Why does Oracle adds NaN to a row in a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461229/when-why-does-oracle-adds-nan-to-a-row-in-a-database-table)

And Oracle even has distinct "Not-a-Number" categories to represent ["infinity"](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/08/positive-infinity.html), to make things even more complicated.

But on Java side, `BigDecimal` does not support `NaN` -- from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), in all conversion methods...

> Throws:
>     `NumberFormatException` - if value is infinite or NaN.

*Note that the JDBC driver masks that exception and displays `NumericOverflow` instead, to make things more complicated to debug...*

---

So your issue looks like that one: [Solr Numeric Overflow (from Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389652/solr-numeric-overflow)
 -- but unfortunately SolR allows to skip errors, while Sqoop does not; so you cannot use the same trick.

In the end, you will have to "mask" these `NaN` values with [Oracle function `NaNVL`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions115.htm#SQLRF06311), using a [free-form query in Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports):

```
$ sqoop import --query 'SELECT x, y, NANVL(z, Null) AS z FROM wtf WHERE $CONDITIONS'
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!!! It was hard to conclude that representation of null values causes the issue. Of course it would be great if this conversion was added to how sqoop reads data just to prevent the error. Now I have to create custom job for this table.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** that answer assumed that your Oracle data was good, and your Sqoop job needed specific configuration to cope with *NUMBER* values. That was not the case, see alternate answer.

---

In theory, it can be solved.

From the **Oracle documentation** about *"Copying Oracle tables to Hadoop"* (within their Big Data appliance), section *"Creating a Hive table"* > *"[About datatype conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57371_01/doc.41/e57351/copy2bda.htm#BIGUG76753)"*...

> NUMBER
>
> - INT when the scale is 0 and the precision is less than 10
> - BIGINT when the scale is 0 and the precision is less than 19
> - DECIMAL when the scale is greater than 0 or the precision is greater than 19

So you **must** find out what is the **actual** range of values in your Oracle table, then you will be able to specify the target Hive column either a `BIGINT` or a `DECIMAL(38,0)` or a `DECIMAL(22,7)` or whatever.

Now, from the **Sqoop documentation** about *"sqoop - import"* > *"[Controlling type mapping](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_type_mapping)"*...

> Sqoop is preconfigured to map most SQL types to appropriate Java or
>   Hive representatives. However the default mapping might not be
>   suitable for everyone and might be overridden by `--map-column-java`
>   (for changing mapping to Java) or `--map-column-hive` (for changing
>   Hive mapping).
>
> Sqoop is expecting comma separated list of mappings *(...)* for
>   example 
> `$ sqoop import ... --map-column-java id=String,value=Integer`

Caveat #1: according to [SQOOP-2103](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2103), you need **Sqoop V1.4.7 or above** to use that option with Decimal, and you need to "URL Encode" the comma, e.g. for `DECIMAL(22,7)`
`--map-column-hive "wtf=Decimal(22%2C7)"`

Caveat #2: in your case, it is not clear whether the overflow occurs when *reading* the Oracle value into a Java variable, or when *writing* the Java variable into the HDFS file -- or even elsewhere. So maybe `--map-column-hive` will not be sufficient.
And again, according to [that post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/decimal-or-java-BigDecimal-support-with-Sqoop-and-AVRO-or/td-p/44948) which points to [SQOOP-1493](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1493), `--map-column-java` does not support Java type `java.math.BigDecimal` until at least Sqoop V1.4.7 *(and it's not even clear whether it is supported in that specific option, and whether it is expected as `BigDecimal` or `java.math.BigDecimal`)*

---

In practice, since Sqoop 1.4.7 is not available in all distros, and since your problem is not well diagnosed, it may not be feasible.

So I would advise to just hide the issue by **converting your rogue Oracle column to a String, at read time**.
Cf. documentation about *"sqoop - import"* > *"[Free-form Query Imports](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports)"*...

> Instead of using the `--table`, `--columns` and `--where` arguments, you can
>   specify a SQL statement with the `--query` argument *(...)* Your query must include the token $CONDITIONS *(...)* For example:
>   `$ sqoop import --query 'SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id WHERE $CONDITIONS' ...`

In your case, `SELECT x, y, TO_CHAR(z) AS z FROM wtf` plus the appropriate formatting inside TO_CHAR so that you don't lose any information due to rounding.

Comment: Thank you. In hive this column has DOUBLE type. It's unbelievably that overflow can happen in the case.  As I wrote earlier I tried to use conversion to_char(mycolumn) with free format  query, and got Oracle error bad number, what is very strange, unless sqoop doesn't like such conversion. I expect that if Oracle is OK with the written value in the column, it's a good number. I only can guess what sqoop does internally, but looks like it can't convert this value to double. I have two such columns, their values were calculated, without these columns I can insert everything.

Comment: Here's how it looks 

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

                at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4381)

                at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getBigDecimal(NumberCommonAccessor.java:2509)

                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBigDecimal(OracleResultSetImpl.java:548)

                at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readBigDecimal(JdbcWritableBridge.java:126)

Comment: at com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readBigDecimal(JdbcWritableBridge.java:97)

                at QueryResult.readFields(QueryResult.java:288)

                at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:244)

                ... 12 more